# Declaring XHTML doctype then using HTML content-type

Tags: html, xhtml, doctype

I noticed a very popular forum I use, which ironically is one of the biggest web-development forums in the world, uses this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" dir="ltr" lang="en" id="vbulletin_html">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
...
```

I know it's a transitional doctype, but if you're going to tell the browser to render the markup as HTML, what on earth was the point in using XHTML? I can't help but think of the wasted time using all those needless closing tags.

This is still more common than people would like, but why is this so? Surely it defeats the whole purpose of using XHTML?

Comment: XHTML is a failed idea. Avoid it. Use pure HTML syntax and `<!doctype html>` instead.

Comment: I completely agree. I personally always use HTML5 markup. I'm just shocked such a popular website could make this strange mistake.

Comment: To further elaborate, the idea of XHTML is that the browsers use an XML parser (instead of an HTML parser) to render the page. However, an XML parser will break on the tiniest error, and also, IE doesn't have an XML parser at all. As a result all pages on the internet are served with the HTML content type, not the XHTML content type, so they are HTML, not XHTML documents. Therefore, the XTML doctype and syntax are useless.

Comment: Good info. Sime. I'm just baffled why someone would go to the trouble of using the extra tags that XHTML uses when they're just going to use the HTML content type.

Comment: @Šime “An XML parser will break on the tiniest error” – this is generally considered a *good* thing.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Hm, I'm not sure about that. It's not convenient. Having any HTML syntax error effectively "kill" my entire web-page, so that it's inaccessible to my visitors, is not an environment I would like to work in. Not everyone, me included, tests his code thoroughly before shipping it. I'm sure there is a significant community of people that create good and useful web-content, but that are not experts on HTML syntax. XML parsers would make it hard for their content to be accessible.

Comment: @Šime On the contrary, it’s extremely convenient because it helps you catch markup errors quickly (and during *development*, *before* your visitors get to see it). Otherwise, the error might not have an immediately visible effect on the layout until you change something months later, and suddenly the layout breaks and you have no clue what’s going on. Your argument is equivalent to saying that having undefined behaviour in C++ code is better than catching errors at compile time, or catching the error early and crashing with an exception. Almost nobody would argue that.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I think my point was that XML parsers would make it hard for amateurs to publish web-content. For instance, a high-school student that is a beginner in HTML, might want to publish a web-page with good content. However, his HTML code might be syntactically invalid (he's a beginner), and he may not be able to make the code valid at all (without external help). With XML parsers, he would not be able to make his content available to the Internet. Basically, the web would be restricted to those content-creators that are able to write syntactically valid HTML code, ...

Comment: ... so the non-programmers/amateurs/beginners would sort-of be discriminated.

Comment: @Šime I maintain that even (or actually *especially*) beginners benefit from strict error checking. Apart from that, less unprofessional content on the web wouldn’t necessarily be a bad thing either.

Comment: I think some of you are forgetting (or unaware) that modern browsers support the XML serialization of HTML5 (sometimes referred to as XHTML5.) Masking errors benefits nobody but lazy developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main practical benefit is that it allows you to use XML in your tool chain up to the point where it is delivered to the browser. Most users don't benefit from this beyond having simple syntax highlighting algorithms in their editors, but it does allow the use of XSLT and other XML tools.

Some people consider XHTML to be stricter (and therefore better) then HTML (although the DTDs for XML are less powerful then SGML so while it removes some exceptions on requirements for tags and attribute quotes, HTML allows a validator to spot problems such as `<a><b><a></a></b></a>`.

Some people just like explicitly closing all their tags.

Some people were introduced to web authoring with XHTML (it was the flavour of the month for more than a few years) and never gave serious consideration to the alternatives.

Comment: Most programming style guides advise explicitness over implicitness. That, combined with XML tool chains, is the main argument for using XHTML over plain HTML.

Comment: Hm seems like a pretty weak argument considering I read somewhere that using the HTML content type will force the browser to convert all XHTML properties (like the closing tags) back to HTML.

Comment: @Lee True but it triggers a different parsing mode in validators.